# Angular Filter based on angular variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to run a filter based on a previously defined variable in angular, this is what I have tried

`<tr ng-repeat="data in servers | filter: { _id: { idc: '" + {{ item._id.idc }} + "'  } }">`

This gives me an error of:

`Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 32-33 ['] in expression [servers | filter: { _id: { idc: '].`
The following code works:

`<tr ng-repeat="data in servers | filter: { _id: { idc: 'LH5' } }">`

Essiently I want to replace `'LH5'` with `item.id.idc`

Comment: `filter: { _id: { idc: item._id.idc  } }` don't use string interpolation

Comment: 1) Why the quotes and concatenation?! 2) Quotes! Within quotes! You are simply terminating the `ng-repeat` attribute too early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need string interpolation. Just pass the variable.

```
filter: { _id: { idc: item._id.idc } }
```